# Access to XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy

Tags: deployment, cors

I am deploying my first app on heroku. (It's a node.js/react app.) The app has deployed successfully, but when I try to login I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<myApp>.herokuapp.com/users' from origin 
'https://<myApp>-front-end.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access- 
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141) explain how to fix this problem with a proxy url, but I am wondering whether I did something wrong in the first place. Following an online tutorial, I deployed the front end and back end separately, and that seems to be causing the problem. Should I have deployed the front end and back end together to avoid this problem? Or is getting around this problem a normal part of deploying an app?

Comment: https://<myApp>.herokuapp.com/users & https://<myApp>-front-end.herokuapp.com both have backends. They’re separate servers running at different origins. You happen to have frontend JavaScript code running at https://<myApp>-front-end.herokuapp.com that’s making a request to https://<myApp>.herokuapp.com/users. So maybe what you’re describing instead is that you have an API endpoint running at https://<myApp>.herokuapp.com/users and you’re wondering if that API endpoint should run on the same server that’s the backend for https://<myApp>-front-end.herokuapp.com. If so the answer is, it depends